# Angular Material - App crashes after using *ngFor on a FormArray for expansion panels

Tags: angular, angular-material, ngfor, formarray, formgroups

First off thanks @AJT_82 for tout advices!

I’ve ben working on a much simpler example of my code reproducing the error can be found at [stackblitz.com/edit/angular-42gobh](http://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-42gobh)
**The problematic line is commented** so that you can check out what the correct result should be. **Just uncomment the** `<div [formGroup]="i"></div>` **to make everything crash**.

Basically, I have a service building the forms for my component and the HTML file uses Angular Material. When an accordion is used for a formArray the application crashes completely and it's impossible to assign the formGroup correctly:

customer-edit.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, FormArray, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CustomerEditService {
  private cusForm: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
    thirdParty: this.fb.group({
      name: this.fb.control(null),
      vat: this.fb.control(null),
      corpoPhone: this.fb.control(null),
      corpoMail: this.fb.control(null),
      corpoWeb: this.fb.control(null),
      activityNumber: this.fb.control(null),
      addresses: this.fb.array([]),
      contacts: this.fb.array([])
    }),
    docRefs: this.fb.group({}),
    commentsArr: this.fb.group({})
  });

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder
    ) {    }

    // **** EMPTY FORMS GETTERS ****

    getAddressForm(address?: any) {
      const addressForm: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
        street: this.fb.control(null),
        streetcomp: this.fb.control(null),
        streetcomp2: this.fb.control(null),
        city: this.fb.control(null),
        cp: this.fb.control(null),
        state: this.fb.control(null),
        country: this.fb.control(null),
        main: this.fb.control(null)
      });
      if (address) {
        addressForm.setValue(address);
      }
      return addressForm;
    }

    getFilledThirdPartyForm(thirdParty?: any) {
      const thirdPartyForm: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
        name: this.fb.control(null, Validators.required),
        vat: this.fb.control(null, Validators.required),
        corpoPhone: this.fb.control(null, Validators.required),
        corpoMail: this.fb.control(null, Validators.required),
        corpoWeb: this.fb.control(null, Validators.required),
        activityNumber: this.fb.control(null),
      });
      if (thirdParty) {
        Object.keys(thirdParty).map(
          el => {
            if (Object.keys(thirdPartyForm.controls).indexOf(el) !== -1 && el !== 'addresses') {
              thirdPartyForm.get(el).setValue(thirdParty[el]);
            }
        });
      }
      return thirdPartyForm;
    }

}
```

And here's the TS file for the component where the form gets built. The form is built based on the JSON object (thirdparty) in "real life" this object comes from a database via a HTTP request:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';
import { CustomerEditService } from '../customer-edit.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-basic-edit',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html'
})

export class testComponent implements OnInit {
  thirdParty: any = 
    {
      "addresses": [
        {
          "street": "AVENIDA ESTADOS UNIDOS, 141",
          "streetcomp": "",
          "streetcomp2": "",
          "city": "SAN BARTOLOME DE TIRAJANA ",
          "cp": "35290",
          "state": "PALMAS (LAS)",
          "country": "spain",
          "main": true
        },
        {
          "street": "OTRA DIRECCION DUMMY",
          "streetcomp": "",
          "streetcomp2": "",
          "city": "MADRID",
          "cp": "280007",
          "state": "MADRID",
          "country": "spain",
          "main": false
        }
      ],
      "contacts": [
        {
          "_id": "5cf0f6f2a3e9cf847c5861af",
          "title": "Mrs.",
          "role": "CFO",
          "firstName": "John",
          "lastName": "Doe",
          "phone": "912345654",
          "mobile": "673369900",
          "thirdParty_id": "5cf0f6d0a3e9cf847c5861aa",
          "addresses": [
            {
              "street": "AVENIDA ESTADOS UNIDOS , 141",
              "streetcomp1": "TUNTE",
              "streetcomp2": "",
              "cp": "35290",
              "city": "SAN BARTOLOME DE TIRAJANA ",
              "state": "PALMAS (LAS)"
            }
          ],
          "email": "jdoe@ketchup.com",
          "auditTrail": {
            "creation": {
              "user_id": "1",
              "creationDate": "1559213796974"
            },
            "modification": [
              {
                "user_id": "1",
                "modifDate": "1559213833358"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ] 
    };

  thirdPartyForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private cusEditService: CustomerEditService
  ) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.thirdPartyForm = this.cusEditService.getFilledThirdPartyForm(this.thirdParty);
    const addresses: any[] = this.thirdParty.addresses;
    const addressesFormArr: FormArray = new FormArray([]);
    addresses.forEach(
      address => {
        const currAddressForm: FormGroup = this.cusEditService.getAddressForm(address);
        addressesFormArr.push(currAddressForm);
      });
    this.thirdPartyForm.setControl(
      'addresses',
      addressesFormArr
    );
    console.log(this.thirdPartyForm.get('addresses'));
  }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log('Submitted');
  }
}
```

And here's the HTML:

```
<h1>Addresses Test</h1>
<form [formGroup]="thirdPartyForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div formArrayName="addresses">
    <mat-accordion>
      <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let address of thirdPartyForm.get('addresses').value; index as i">
        <mat-expansion-panel-header>
          {{ address.city }}
        </mat-expansion-panel-header>
          <div [formGroupName]="i"> <!-- UNCOMMENTING THIS LINE MAKES EVERYTHING CRASH -->
          </div>
      </mat-expansion-panel>
    </mat-accordion>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Well the stackblitz doesn't work because of http-requests. Also there is way to much code. You should isolate to the specific issue you are facing and show that by creating a [mcve]. GREAT, that you have provided a stackblitz, but it's pretty much useless if it doesn't show the issue you are having ;)

Comment: Just as I feared, trying to reproduce the problem on a more simplistic example doesn't reproduce the error... : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-42gobh

Comment: Okay, well that is kinda good. Now add piece by piece more of your code, until you can reproduce the same error. I'd be happy to take a look, and others probably too... but there is just so much code, that I don't think anyone is going to take a second look to try and even figure out from where those code snippets are in the stackblitz you originally presented, there's just too much. Not trying to be mean or anything.

Comment: Will do. Thanks for the follow-up. I'll let you know when I crashes! ;)

Comment: Done! :P ... adding angular Material (expansion panel) broke everything just like in my app... (apparently) I left the `<div [formGroupName]="i">` commented (piece that makes the code break) so that you see how it's supposed to work just comment it out to make the browser crash...

Comment: Try <div [formgroup]="address"> instead?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

wish I could tell you the exact why of this, but the solution is changing your iteration to be over controls instead of values to make it work:

```
<mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let address of thirdPartyForm.get('addresses').controls; index as i" >
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        {{ address.get('city').value }}
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <div [formGroupName]="i">
        <input formControlName="city">
    </div> 
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

my best guess here is that by accessing values to iterate and trying to nest a form group name inside it, you've created some kind of loop where the content keeps getting re rendered as accessing the formGroupName directive causes value to re evaluate, while controls don't as it's a static property. Value in a form control is really a getter under the hood, so it can re evaluate. Function iterations are impure so they continuously get reevaluated, and as a result, in an ngFor, the content keeps getting re rendered (absent a trackBy clause).

I noted that iterating value seems to work without an accordion, so I'm guessing it's also something to do with the sub component aspect here where the constant re-rendering causes it to run out of memory and crash.  Might be worth registering this on their github, as they should at least document that you should not try to do this.

I went ahead and added a test directive that logs in it's constructor to some plain divs where I iterated by value, both with and without a form group name directive inside.  I found that, where n = length of the form array, the directive would instantiate n*2 times without a formGroupName directive inside.  but with the formGroupName, it instantiated n^2 + 2n times. So for sure, iterating values causes it to evaluate twice, and then for some reason adding that directive causes it to evaluate again for each group in the array on top, and thus render the content exponentially.  In contrast, using controls to iterate, caused the directive to instantiate just n times as you'd expect.

Still not totally sure on the why of this all though, just know for sure that this happens and was the cause of your crash.

demo blitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fgqytp?file=src/app/test-component/test.component.html

unrelated side note, you can use formbuilder like this:

```
  const thirdPartyForm: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
    name: [null, Validators.required],
    vat: [null, Validators.required],
    corpoPhone: [null, Validators.required],
    corpoMail: [null, Validators.required],
    corpoWeb: [null, Validators.required],
    activityNumber: null
  })
```

"leaf" values in form builder are assumed to be controls, and it accepts that array syntax to add validators as needed.  This is kind of the main benefit of using formbuilder vs just doing `new FormGroup({key: new FormControl(null)})`

Comment: Hey Bryan! Thanks for your answer. Let me check it out and validate your answer!

Comment: glad to help out

Comment: I was curious, so i added a test directive that logs when constructed to some plain old divs being iterated by value both with a formGroupName inside and without. with a formGroupName, it gets instantiated n^2 + n times, without, it gets instantiated n*2 times where n is the length of the form array.  so yea, that was definitely what was crashing your app, but still not sure exactly why this occurred. some quirk of adding a formGroupName directive inside causes value to re evaluate exponentially

Comment: n^2+2n*** times